# How to count the number of observations in a VAR and when to apply equation-by-equation estimation?

Tags: vector-autoregression

I am dealing with VARs in which the dimension of the systems, k, can become quite big. My question is how are the number of observations counted in a VAR? The reason I am asking is the following passage from a recent paper (reference below) on regularized VAR:

"Those characteristics allow estimating the VAR model equation-by-equation often by the ordinary least squares method. This is good news as we are estimating the U.S. real estate return dynamics of all states, meaning that  = 51 and, hence, a joint estimation with a lag length of one would mean that  + 2 = 2652 parameters need to be estimated, but we only have  = 418 observations (2652 ≫ 418), which would mean that this model cannot be estimated. Using the equation-by-equation estimation procedure makes this feasible as it just estimates,  + 1 = 52 parameters (52 < 418).".

My intuition would say that you have T observations of a k-dimensional vector. However, from the quoted passage it seems that the total number of observations in the system must be counted as T*k if you apply estimation on an equation-by-equation basis. Which is the correct interpretation? Moreover, the authors state that restricting the covariance matrix of the error term to be diagonal is what enables them to estimate on an equation-by-equation basis. Is imposing such restrictions on the covariance matrix of the error term a necessary and sufficient condition to on an equation-by-equation basis. If not, why, and what then are the relevant condition(s)?

Reference: Gabauer, D., Gupta, R., Marfatia, H. A., & Miller, S. M. (2024). Estimating US housing price network connectedness: Evidence from dynamic Elastic Net, Lasso, and ridge vector autoregressive models. International Review of Economics & Finance, 89, pp. 349-362, quoted passage on pp. 352.

Comment: No, it is not a necessary condition. There are many possible sets of restrictions that reduce the number of parameters to be estimated and thus make estimation feasible in smaller samples.

Comment: What then are the neccessary conditions to e.g. estimate equation-by-equation, since apparently by doing this you gain an enormous amount of parameters?

Comment: For point estimates, it is enough to have more observations than parameters in an equation. For inference involving more than one parameter, especially when said parameters come from different equations, more data will be needed or more restrictions will have to be placed.